# Creating a Properties with the name as a value in a String

Tags: java, properties

I have a `String` which contains a value, say "`test`".
Now I need to create a `Properties` with a name as the value of `String`.
To be clear,

```
String propName = "test";
```

I need the logic which can create the following :

```
Properties test = new Properties();
```

Reason for this Requirement : I have an array of `String`, whose `Properties` have to be created.

Comment: You can't do this in Java.

Comment: I think you have to use some kind of Reflection in Java to do this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: You could store the properties in a map indexed by the property name strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reason for this Requirement : I have an array of String, whose
>   Properties have to be created.

You could use a [`Map<String, Properties>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to achieve that.

```
Map<String, Properties> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("test", new Properties());
```

Comment: Then how would you call the getProperty() ?

Comment: @KarthikVU `myMap.get("test").getProperty()`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you are intend to add the values for each of the `Properties` so I'll assume you just want some default value for now.

```
String[] keys = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
Properties props = new Properties();

for (String k: keys) {
    props.put(k, "some value");
}

// Prints out the property value
System.out.println("Value of test2 property: " + props.getProperty("test2"));
```

You only need a single `Property` object to store multiple key->value `Strings` as properties.

Comment: +1 This might also be the solution, it's not 100% clear what the op is asking.

Comment: I am sorry, But the Question was, to Create a new property from the array. Here we are creating values in a single property.

Comment: None of the answers here give you exactly what you ask for. What you are asking is how to generate *variable* names from an array of strings. The only way to achieve exactly what you originally asked for is some form of compile time code generation.